# importing Access tables into SAS

Tags: sas

I have a access database contains many tables. I have used libname statement to import them into SAS. access tables were not in the form of sas datasets. they have started with numbers and has space in table name.

I cant use the datasets imported into sas from Access. Please anyone help me how to read those datasets in SAS.

Thanks,
Ravi

Comment: Thanks for your answer and valuable suggestion. I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

As long as they're under 32 characters long, you should be able to read them with [name literals](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/65287/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p18cdcs4v5wd2dn1q0x296d3qek6.htm#n0qc68k2iyhs5kn1t2bvt41myhn1).

First, set [option validmemname=EXTEND](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lesysoptsref/64892/HTML/default/n10nwm6blrcrtmn0zdcwyxlwxfjh.htm).  Then you can reference the names like so:

```
data want;
  set accdb.'my dataset'n;
run;
```